# Error on Opening Genexus 17 Kb in Genexus 18

Tags: genexus

Error Log:

========== Preserve Knowledge Base style based on themes started ==========
No version update was required.
Failed: Preserve Knowledge Base style based on themes

I receive this error in every single KB when i close on Genexus 17 and Open on Genexus 18.

---

```
Timestamp: 13/02/2023 14:09:47
Message: HandlingInstanceID: 24c7ba00-4ede-4a8d-b273-6b13d512b349
An exception of type 'Artech.Common.Diagnostics.GxException' occurred and was caught.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
02/13/2023 14:09:47
Type : Artech.Common.Diagnostics.GxException, Artech.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6f5bf81c27b6b8aa
Message : Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'ObjectSelectorControl'.
Source : 
Help link : 
Exception Data
Product : GeneXus 18
Version : 18.0.167910 U1
Exception.Severity : Error
TargetSite : 
HResult : -2146232832
Stack Trace : The stack trace is unavailable.
Additional Info:

MachineName : MACHINNENAME
TimeStamp : 13/02/2023 17:09:47
FullName : Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=79a65ef946496ecc
AppDomainName : GeneXus.exe
ThreadIdentity : MACHINNENAME\WINDOWSUSER
WindowsIdentity : MACHINNENAME\WINDOWSUSER
    Inner Exception
    ---------------
    Type : System.ObjectDisposedException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    Message : Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'ObjectSelectorControl'.
    Source : System.Windows.Forms
    Help link : 
    ObjectName : ObjectSelectorControl
    TargetSite : Void CreateHandle()
    HResult : -2146232798
    Stack Trace :    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
       at Artech.Core.UI.ToolWindows.ObjectSelectorControl.StopPainting()
       at Artech.Core.UI.ToolWindows.ObjectSelectorControl.OnUpdateDataSource(List`1 items)
       at Artech.Core.UI.ToolWindows.ObjectSelectorControl.set_Objects(List`1 value)
       at Artech.Core.UI.ToolWindows.WorkWithObjectsEditor.Artech.Core.UI.ToolWindows.IObjectBrowser.UpdateControl(ObjectBrowserHelperResult result)
       at Artech.Core.UI.ToolWindows.ObjectBrowserHelper.WorkerRunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.AsyncOperationCompleted(Object arg)


Category: Default Category
Priority: 0
EventId: 100
Severity: Error
Title:Genexus Application Exception
Machine: MACHINNENAME
Application Domain: GeneXus.exe
Process Id: 6420
Process Name: C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus18\GeneXus.exe
Win32 Thread Id: 3696
Thread Name: 
Extended Properties: AdvancedInformation.Product - GeneXus 18
AdvancedInformation.Version - 18.0.167910 U1
Exception.Severity - Error
```

Comment: Do you have any more information in the GeneXus log file, or in the Windows Event Viewer?
If not, I'd suggest opening a support ticket so that we can prompt more information, or even a simple KB that reproduces the issue, and take a look.

Comment: @Fede i update my Question with error on Windows Log

Comment: @Genexudo Maybe try resetting the workspace. Run `genexus /NoWorkspace` or alternatively run `genexus /nolastkb` and manually close the offending tool window prior to opening the KB.

Comment: @gusbro Either way you said I have the same problem. I even made a test of copying the MDF and LDF to another directory and opening it via Database Genexus gives the same error.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?